# How to configure jest to find assets in Vite project?

Tags: jestjs, vite

I am using Vite to create a typescript app with react. The default set up for a Vite project is to put assets in the

> src/assets/react.svg

folder. Trying to set up jest for testing, I am getting an error when I run my jest tests. The error is "could not locate module ./assets/react.svg mapped as myname/*tests*/*mocks*/fileMock.js"

You can see my jest.config.ts file below. This is the directory structure (relevant files listed only)

```
src/_tests_/_mocks_/fileMock.js
src/_tests_/_mocks_/styleMock.js
src/assets
App.css
App.tsx
Index.tsx
vite.environment.d.ts
jest.config.js
tsconfig.json
vite.config.ts
```

Question: how can I configure jest to find the assets?

```
export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    //testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest" 
    // process `*.tsx` files with `ts-jest`
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|png)$': '<rootDir>/_tests_/__ mocks __/fileMock.js',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `moduleNameMapper` is setup incorrectly, currently it evaluates to `/projectroot/_tests_/__ mocks __/fileMock.js` which is not the intended path

Your file is inside `src` so the path should be `<rootDir>/src/...`

`rootDir`: is the absolute path to the root level for your project

Comment: Thank you it worked, but I apparently don't understand the path. I'm having trouble with css import now. This is what I have in module mapping.   '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/src/_tests/_mocks_/styleMock.js'  See OP for App.css location. Jest is telling me to check that mapping, and also says "resolver: undefined" Can you explain why Jest could not locate App.css or should I add different question?

Comment: In my styleMock.js file, I only have module.exports = {};

Comment: I solved the problem I asked in the comments using  '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy', . Thanks for the answer.